# create a new field which will have part contents from text search in existing field in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Requirement is to create a new field which has part contents from text search in existing field in mongoDB

For example: there is a field 'description' in a collection 'stores' say
description: There is a heavy discount to do budget shopping according to the your pocket, so enjoy shopping this christmas.

Now requirement is to search text 'heavy discount' from above description field and copy few words from searched text 'a heavy discount to do budget shopping' into a new field say 'result'.

So the new field 'result' will have following data:
result: 'a heavy discount to do budget shopping'

Tried search text and add field through aggregate operators, but not able to get the actual result.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you tried. An attempt is generally expected to be shown even if it does not get you the desired result.

Comment: db.stores.aggregate(
 [
  {
   $project: { "result": { $cond: { if: { $gte: [ { $indexOfCP: [ "$description", "Coffee" ] }, 0] }, then: { $substrCP:  ["$description", { $indexOfCP: [ "$description", "Coffee" ] }, 20]}, else: "Not Found" }}}
  }
 ]
)

Now my issue is to add field: result to the collection 'stores'.
Is this possible to add result field to existing stores collection on which m working without new collection?
Please note, I dont want to create a new collection.

Comment: tried this as well: db.stores.aggregate(
 [
  {
   $match: {
    $text: { $search: "coffee" }
   }
  },
  {
   $addFields: { "result": { $cond: { if: { $gte: [ { $indexOfCP: [ "$description", "coffee" ] }, 0] }, then: { $substrCP:  ["$description", { $indexOfCP: [ "$description", "coffee" ] }, 10]}, else: "Not Found" }}}
  }
 ]
)

Comment: Now my issue is to add field: 'result' to the collection 'stores'.
Is this possible to add 'result' field to existing 'stores' collection on which m working without new collection?
Please note, I dont want to create a new collection.